# My Notification does not go away even when i force close my app

Tags: android, notifications

My Notification does not go away even when i force close my app. , ie. when i open the multitask window and swipe it off but my persistant notification is not going away.

This is my notification populate method:

```
public void populateNotification(Boolean bool) {
    int notifyID = 1;
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Set Content Text");
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Set Content Title");
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (bool) {
        notificationManager.notify(notifyID, notificationBuilder.build());
    } else {
        notificationManager.cancel(notifyID);
    }
```

This is my onDestroy method:

```
`
public void onDestroy() {
        if (cameraAPIself != null) {
            cameraAPIself.destroyCamera();
        }
        if (cameraAPI2self != null) {
            cameraAPI2self.destroyCamera();
        }
        populateNotification(false);
        super.onDestroy();
    }`
```

Basically what my app does is it shows notification when flash is ON. But when i force close my app ie. when flash is ON (when notification gets populated) , the notification is not going away as there is no need of the notification since the application is no more active. Can anyone guide me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calling onDestroy() does not always work.**

onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called all the time (see [here](https://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)).

("*App Process killed if apps with higher priority need memory*")

Also, the documentation on [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) has to say this about onDestroy method :

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's
>   hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so
>   it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

**Using Services**

So what you can do is, create a Service (not *sticky*), in that Service you override [`onTaskRemoved`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent))() method, and in that method you call cancel on your Notification.

This is what the documentation states about `onTaskRemoved` -

> This is called if the service is currently running and the user has
>   removed a task that comes from the service's application.